# Sub select query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to take data from a row and make 2 seperate columns from the data.I need to add the list with the price, and the perffered with the price. I have a perferred+price and a list+price. I need to make a column of list price and a column of the perferred price. When using a sub select I get an error.Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. I am new at SQL and need help please.

Google and other people

```
SELECT 
    PriceListID + '   ' + CAST(Price1 AS VARCHAR(10)),
    (SELECT PriceListID + '   ' + CAST(Price1 AS VARCHAR(10))
     FROM Inprclst
     WHERE PriceListID = 'LIS')
FROM 
    Inprclst
WHERE 
    PriceListID = 'PRF'
```

Comment: Please show us a sample of your data and a sample of the result exactly as it should appear. That will go a long way for us to help you.

Comment: Use CASE When for this. [CASE When] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN  PriceListID = 'PRF' THEN PriceListID + '   ' + CAST(Price1 AS VARCHAR(10)) END),
       MAX( CASE WHEN  PriceListID = 'LIS' THEN PriceListID + '   ' + CAST(Price1 AS VARCHAR(10)) END),
FROM Inprclst
WHERE PriceListID IN( 'PRF', 'LIS');
```